# Как сделать такие пятиугольники (+адаптивные) через css?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Думаю, что их стоит сделать `svg polygon`, но как это лучше реализовать, чтобы они и адаптивными были и подгонялись под ширину блока, в котором находятся?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Решение SVG

*Решение адаптивно. Работает во всех браузерах.*

Вёрстка не сломается при изменении масштаба, так как все оформительские элементы: текст, патч, градиент находятся внутри `SVG`
Если будет необходимость поменять начальные размеры блока, то нужно изменить проценты родительского контейнера `.container`

```css
.container {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #131824;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 264 264">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad"
      x1="0%"
      y1="0%"
      x2="100%"
      y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FD712C"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F32276"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text x="80" y="30" fill="black" font-size="24px" font-family="sans-serif">Standard</text>
    <path d="m0.6 48.3 262.7 0 0 78.8L131.7 167 0.6 127Z" id="path4138" fill="url(#grad)"/>
    <text x="70" y="115" fill="white" font-size="54px" font-family="sans-serif">24.0</text> 
   <text x="90" y="220" fill="#777777" font-size="20px" font-family="sans-serif">Five User</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

А чтобы была адаптивной,  ее надо внедрить как фоновую картинку.

Сохранить сей пример в отдельном файле `name.svg`

> background-Image: url(путь к файлу name.svg);
>
> background-size: cover;

И второй вариант. Прописать прямо в `css`.

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg id="wrapper_svg_1" viewBox="0 0 500 300" width="500" height="300"><style>#wrapper_svg_1{background: red;}</style><polygon fill="green"  stroke="none" stroke-width="1" points="0 0, 500 0, 500    150, 250 300, 0 150, "></polygon></svg>');
 background-size: cover;
```

```html
<svg id="wrapper_svg_1" viewBox="0 0 500 300" width="500" height="300">
 <style>
  #wrapper_svg_1{
  background: red;
  }
 </style>
 <polygon fill="green"  stroke="none" stroke-width="1" points="0 0, 500 0, 500    150, 250 300, 0 150, ">                    
 </polygon>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение CSS `clip-path`. Но надо учесть тот факт, что в `IE && EDGE`, работать не будет.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFDD00, #FF00AE);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 50% 100%, 0 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 50% 100%, 0 60%);
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span class="title">  Standard</span>
  <div class="triangle">
    24.0
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li> bla bla bla</li>
    <li> bla bla bla</li>
    <li> bla bla bla</li>
    <li> bla bla bla</li>
    <li> bla bla bla</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```